# Prevent validation when using __doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using __doPostBack manually in JavaScript, however it is triggering my validation on the server side. When the page refreshes, it has validated the fields on the page and is displaying the errors in the ValidationSummary control.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I am not calling Page.Validate() on the server.

Comment: I think I'm going to add a hidden button to the page with CausesValidation set to false and use JavaScript to simulate a click on that button.

Answer (score 0):

Use validation groups. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could look at WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions for controlling the postback, it allows you to specify options (such as causes validation) when doing the postback.  I haven't used it for years so I'm not sure if it is still the best way of doing things, if it is indeed still used at all.

Edit: adding an example:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("buttonname", "", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [client-side api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479045#aspplusvalid_clientside) and inspect the Page_IsValid property. In that link you should see a section for the client api.